Can I transform columns grouped in a table into new queries in Power Query?
I have a query in power query where I am grouping rows and this is my result:

I need to transform each Table into a new query, but in the future I will have many rows and it will be impossible to do it manually for all of them. Is there a way to do this with M or in some other automatic way?
I've tried a few ways with code but I always have to do it one by one.

No. Within powerquery you cannot convert each cell [Table] into its own query.  You would have to set them up in advance or use VBA to create them
